# How to prove "Logarithms grow more slowly than polynomials"

Tags: logarithms, asymptotics

"Logarithms grow more slowly than polynomials. That is, $Θ(\lg n)$ grows more slowly than $Θ(n^a)$ for any positive constant a."

if $$y_1= x^{\frac{1}{2}}$$ and $$y_2 = \log (x)$$

by comparing the graphs can say  $y_1 \gt y_2$

But, is there a way to prove this?

Comment: You can compare their derivatives and show the difference.

Comment: because exponential grows faster than polynomials ...

Comment: This question has been asked at least one time here!

Comment: I don't understand what does the mean of `You can compare their derivatives and show the difference`

Comment: @Aniket ${}{{}}{}$

Comment: @NayanaAdassuriya  What i meant has been shown by V.C.  l'Hôpital's rule uses derivatives after all. Anyway, I was asking you to find the derivatives of $f(x)=log x$ and $g(x)=x^a$. Then show that $f'(x)<<<g'(x)$ and $f'(x)-g'(x) \to\infty$ as $x\to\infty$

Answer (score 3):

Actually, even more is true. For $p>0$ and $q>0$, we have that
$$
\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\log^px}{x^q}
 =\lim_{x\to\infty}\Bigl(\frac{\log x}{x^{q/p}}\Bigr)^p
 =\Bigl(\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\log x}{x^{q/p}}\Bigr)^p
 =\Bigl(\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac1{(q/p)x^{q/p}}\Bigr)^p=0
$$
using continuity and [l'Hôpital's rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule).

Answer (score 1):

May use
$$\lim _{x\to0}\frac{\log (\frac{1}{x})}{\sqrt{\frac{1}{x}}}=0$$

Comment: In what sense does this not provide an answer ?

Answer (score 0):

Well, for proving that any $\log(a)$ with positive, non-$1$ real bases grows slower than $a^p$ for any $p>0$ is pretty.  We will start $a$ at $1$.  When we double $a$, the logarithm will, by definition, increase a linear amount, while the polynomial's output will be multiplied by $2^p$.  Then it is so simple it could be an axiom; exponential growth$>$linear growth. I'll prove it anyway.  $p>0$ so b=2^p>1, and since a is at 1 or higher, $ab>a$.  So, $ab$ grows a nonzero amount.  This amount is equal to $ab-a=a(b-1)$.  This is positive since $b>1$ and $a>1$ so $b-1>0$.  This is compounded next iteration: it grows more, and what's more, a non-zero amount more!  Eventually, $a$ approaches $\infty$ as iterations approach $\infty$. By this point, the linear equation has as well, but now $a(b-1)$ is HUGE, and as we go further, it gets bigger, and eventually its derivative starts outpacing that of the linear equation, and by larger and larger margins.  Since any $ab-a-\log(2)$ after a given value of $a$ will be greater than $1$, and at least for finite numbers $E(0, n) 1 \to\infty$, its derivative will outpace that of the linear equation by just that- infinity. Let a approach infinity some more, and the proof is complete.  Polynomials grow faster than logarithms.

Comment: Could have been simpler but whatever.